# RabbitMQ consumer android issue

Tags: java, android, messaging, rabbitmq

I have followed this guide to setup rabbitMQ for android.

http://simonwdixon.wordpress.com/2011/06/03/getting-started-with-rabbitmq-on-android-part-1/

The problem I am facing is on the line `mConsumer.connectToRabbitMQ()` in the ActivityHome, I have changed it to:

```
mOutput.append(“\n”+mConsumer.connectToRabbitMQ());
```

now when I have the wrong server, it prints false as expected however when I have the right server it does not print anything. In fact it does not even print the @string/hello which it should anyways..

The app does not consume messages and I think this could be the reason.. Also I have used loger and found out that the error must be on this method because I can logg before the call however I cannot logg anything after the call.

Any help would be greatly appreciated..
Thanks!